# EmberJS - Using a custom layout/template instead of applcation.hbs

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

As a Rails developer who started messing around with EmberJS one week ago, I want to know if it's possible to use custom layout instead of the provided applictaion.hbs? 
Like we do it in rails:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  layout :resolve_layout

  # ...
```

Comment: you might find this very useful in order to have a better understanding of the order in which hooks are executed (and what hooks you have available): https://alexspeller.com/ember-diagonal/

Comment: @VictorNitu it is indeed very useful. Thanks Victor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you can, but you have to override it in the view, not the controller. You're looking for the [`templateName`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#property_templateName) property that will allow you to override the default template. You might also want to look at the [`layoutName`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#property_layoutName) property, since it's closely related. (You can read about the difference [here](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/views/adding-layouts-to-views/).)

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'something_other_than_application'
});
```

Or if you're using Ember CLI:

```
// app/views/application.js
export default Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'something_other_than_application'
});
```

Comment: Also, if you want to be more fancy, and render different templates into different outlets, or render multiple non-default templates you can find more info here: http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/routing/rendering-a-template/

Comment: Thanks a lot Kori, I will give it a try tonight.

Comment: @GJK Thanks for Your answer. But overriding the "app/views/application.js" will replace the original "application.hbs".
What I want to have is just define custom template for specific view.

Thanks in advance,
Hendry I.

Comment: You don't have to override the application view, that was just an example. You can override _any_ view and change the default template.

Comment: @GJK Thanks a lot, I'm gonna give a try.